# How to get Optin and Optout information from Sitecore EXM?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I have a client using Sitecore 8.2 and EXM 4.0.1. For GDPR reason we wanted to capture the opt-in and opt out of every contact.

If you export the Common Global Opt-out list, it will contain only the following columns "Identifier - FirstName - Surname - Email". There is no information about opt-out date and time.

My question, is there a way to add the opt-out date and time to the exported list?

And where can I find information about the opt-out and the opt-in in the database (which table), knowing that we use the default subscription options from Sitecore for opt-in and opt-out?

Answer (score 1):

You will find all the information about opt-in and opt-out in **Contacts collection** in Analytics db in Mongo.

If you use List Manager for opt-in, or EXM unsubscribe for opt-out, Sitecore stores this information to array under **Tags.Entries.ContactLists.Values** element. There is ID of the list, to which you assigned the contact and a timestamp.